# Pseudo-code algorithm to calculate all permutations of N values chosen from N unequal vectors without repetition

Tags: algorithm, set, permutation, pseudocode

This question is for a program I am trying to write which involves connecting chains of physical parts together. I believe I have distilled it down into the simplest form of the question.  I would also appreciate if someone knows any additional words that describe this problem, as about 30 min of searching for related questions hasn't even turned up a name for this problem.

You have N vectors.  If you choose one value from each vector and do not allow any repeats, you will have one permutation of the type I am trying to find.  What is a pseudo-code algorithm to find all of them without brute forcing?

Example:
You have the vectors

```
v1=[1 2]   v2=[1 2 3]   v3=[1 2 3 4]
```

(Edit note: The nesting of the vectors is unintentional and cannot be leveraged in the algorithm.)
You pick values from each of the vectors and don't allow repeats.

```
Value 1 is from v1 ---> 2
Value 2 is from v2 ---> 1   
Value 3 is from v3 ---> 4

Resulting permutation is [2 1 4].
```

This is one allowable permutation.  Here is an example of a permutation that is not allowed because it repeats.

```
Value 1 is from v1 ---> 2
Value 2 is from v2 ---> 1
Value 3 is from v3 ---> 2    

Resulting permutation is [2 1 2], which is invalid due to repeats.
```

What is an algorithm to find all valid permutations?

Bonus points if you can calculate how many permutations there are before calculating them.

I'll be sure to post back if I can come up with an answer before anyone else can.

Comment: Could you provide a short example of inputs and desired result?

Comment: Definitely.  Edited the question to provide an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you give has nested vectors, meaning that the entries in `v_i` are a subset of those in `v_{i+1}`. If this is indeed the general case for your application, then the number of solutions is simply:

```
n_1 * (n_2 - 1) * ... * (n_k - (k-1))
```

where `n_i` is the length of `v_i` and there are `k` nested vectors.

As far as algorithms are concerned, if you want to generate all possible solutions, then I cannot see a better way than to choose from each successive vector after eliminating already selected entries.

If you aren't nested, a good way to visualize this problem is as a [Marriage Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) in the following sense. Make `k` vertices corresponding to the given `k` vectors

```
v_1  v_2 ...  v_k
```

and another `m` vertices corresponding to the distinct entries of the combined vectors

```
a_1 a_2 ... a_m
```

Then connect `a_i` to `v_j` if and only if `a_i` appears in `v_j`. The goal is to find a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) between the `v`s and the `a`s that touches all of the `v`'s. That is, choose `k` edges so that each `v_i` is an endpoint of exactly one edge.

Any of the standard algorithms, e.g. using augmented paths, will work to find one solution or generate them all.

Comment: PengOne, the nesting of the vectors was unintentional.  Regardless, I think I have to study the marriage problem link you supply so that I can understand the rest of your response which addresses the unnested case.  I think this may be some next-level business of the type that mere mortal mechanical engineers like myself find daunting.  Will return to this in 20 hours or so and see if I can understand and respond.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Shaun Read a bit on matchings in the wikipedia article, but the easiest is to make a simple example, even with the nested example you gave. This really does boil down to matchings, so eventually you'll need to know about those. Luckily and unluckily, there is a great deal of literature on the subject. There are also well-known algorithms to solve these problems.

Comment: OK, wow, this graph theory stuff seems to relate very highly to the "chains of physical parts" program that I mention I am trying to attack in the question.  It also seems like interesting stuff just for general engineering knowledge.  Thanks again.

Comment: Further research indicates that the graph that you suggest constructing from the `a_i`s and `v_j`s is a bipartite graph.  I am going to look for algorithms which will find all maximum matchings of a bipartite graph which satisfy the condition of touching all `v_j`s.

Comment: @PengOne... Any suggestions on where to find algorithms for finding all perfect matchings of bipartite graphs where the disjointed sets do not contain an equal number of verticies?

Comment: @Shaun Sure. Look into Hall's Marriage Theorem. Most good algorithms books will have a blurb on it, and the wikipedia article to which I linked covers the basics. Set theoretically, you're looking for a **transversal** of the given sets. I think this often goes under the name of **Ford–Fulkerson algorithm**, though I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this problem incrementally. Let s1, s2, s3,..,sk be the solutions involving v1, v2, .., vn. Now with vn+1 for every current solution si and element j (j in vn+1), see if j is already in si, if not then add it to your new collection (corresponding to n+1).

1. Initialize S={ {j} for j in v1 }
2. For n=2..m:

   1. newS = {}
   2. for j in vn

      1. for s in S

         1. if j not in s add sU{j} to newS
            S = newS
3. return S

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not following the part about vn+1.  Why would I want to add new vectors to chose from?  The vn vectors are part of the problem definition which I am picturing as unchanging.  Sorry, I really did read your code closely, but I still am not following.  Thanks for your response, though.

Comment: @Shaun What I am saying is if s is a solution to (v1, v2, .., vn), and t is an element of vn+1, we can just check if t is in s, if not, sU{t} is a solution to (v1, v2, ..., vn+1)

Comment: What is vn+1?  What function is U{t}?